# IE Not Waiting for content to load from ajax call

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, pageload

I am trying to apply a jquery scrollbar to a div that is populated with content from another local jquery call. My problem is that IE does not seem to wait for the content in the div to load, before calling the script for the scrollbar...hence, the scrollbar does not work correctly.

- All other browsers work fine, IE (ver. 8, 9 ) is the only one not working.
- when the div contains static html code, IE works fine
- the call to the scroll function is inside a window.load

The strange thing:  IF i stick an alert() call before calling the scroll code, it will work.

I have tried adding a setTimeout() function, but that did not work.

The code looks like this

```
<head>
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          // ajax call to populate scrollable div with html content
       });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="scrollableDiv">

       // content populated by script call above

    </div>

    <...... lots more html here .....>
    <!-- very bottom of page -->
    <script>
       $(window).load(function(){
          // alert ("IF I ADD THIS ALERT, EVERYTHING WORKS FINE IN IE");
         $('.scrollableDiv').ClassyScroll();

       });
    </script>
  </body>
```

Any ideas???

Comment: I've heard of IE being weird when you use both document.ready and window.load - have you tried just doing everything in document.ready?

Comment: Could you not just make $('.scrollableDiv').ClassyScroll(); fire at the end of the function you use to 'populate scrollable div' ?

Comment: might be possible that `// call function to populate scrollable div with html content` is finishing after the window load event. depending on your version of IE, document.ready might actually be firing on window load rather than domready due to missing functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jquery Ajax will help](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

It appears that you're loading the content of scrollableDiv via an ajax call perhaps?  If so then that data probably will not be there when the window.load occurs.  window.load does not wait for asychronous calls to complete.

The solution for that would be to put the $('.scrollableDiv').ClassyScroll(); at the end of your $(document).ready(function() {}); or put it in the success callback of an ajax call.

I do the ajax thing all the time in jquery it would look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function(req, settings) {
        // display a please wait spinner
    },
    complete: function(req, status) {
        // hide the please wait spinner
        // also a possible place to put code you want run after the DOM has changed
    },
    async: true,  // could omit as this is the default
    data: {param1:foo, param2:bar},
    dataType: "html",
    error: function(req, status, err) {
        // report the bad error
    },
    success: function(data, status, req) {
              // do the fun stuff here
    },
    type: "POST",
    url: someURL
});
```

Comment: I thought that at first too, but then he doesn't mention that it doesn't work in other browsers, and if he's doing ajax, it wouldn't work in any browser consistently

Comment: You're right Kevin with one tweak...it wouldn't work consistently in any browser.  It COULD work at any time in any browser if the fist call happens to complete before the second.

Comment: Yes, i am using an ajax call to populate the scrollable div.  is there any way to test and see when that code is ready, then run the scroll function?  I've tried using $('.tagInScrollContent').length to check for the existence of the html generated by the ajax call, but did not have success.   I am puzzled why it's only IE that has the problem....

Comment: @itrickski yes, ajax requests have a complete and a success callback.

Comment: Then the reason you are seeing different results per browser is likely due to domready being triggered on window load in IE8/9 rather than on domready with the version of jquery you're using.

Comment: @KevinB could you provide a short sample code as how this test could work?

Comment: yep, put your code in the success or complete callbacks...example provided above.

Answer (score 1):

`$(document).ready(function() {`

Your div's content is populated when document is ready.

`$(window).load(function(){`

Your `ClassyScroll` function is called whenever your page is totally loaded.

We would need to know what you're doing to populate your div but it's probably async and doesn't block load event from firing.

Anyway, it's usually a bad idea to use both of them for a same functionality. What's i'd suggest is to simply call `ClassyScroll` whenever you know your div is populated (right after if synchronous, on a callback if asynchronous).

Something like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // call function to populate scrollable div with html content
    populateDivWhatever();
    // call your classyscroll function
    $('.scrollableDiv').ClassyScroll();
});
```